# How do I render html content for boxes inside a loop in Shiny?

Tags: r, loops, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to build a Shiny dashboard that responds to user inputs by displaying a series of boxes with nicely formatted html content. Because the user's selections determine how many boxes will be displayed, I'm using `lapply()` to render the boxes on the server side and then pushing the results of that process to `uiOutput()` on the ui side.

It's working with one crucial exception: the html content isn't appearing in the boxes. I don't get any error messages or warnings; I just don't get any content inside the boxes, other than the reactive titles.

What follows is a simple, reproducible example. What do I need to do differently to get `contents` to appear inside the boxes in the body of the ui?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

dat <- data.frame(food = c("hamburger", "hot dog", "pizza", "kale salad"),
                  price = c("$2.50", "$1.50", "$2.00", "$3.50"),
                  peanut_gallery = c("beefy!", "dachsund!", "pie time!", "healthy!"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

### UI ###

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "My Food App", titleWidth = 400)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width = 400,

  fluidRow(column(width = 12,

    checkboxGroupButtons(
      inputId = "my_food",
      label = "Pick a food",
      choices = c("hamburger", "hot dog", "pizza", "kale salad"),
      selected = NULL
    )

  ))

)

body <- dashboardBody(

  fluidRow(

    uiOutput("little_boxes")

  )

)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body, skin = "black")

### SERVER ###

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$little_boxes <- renderUI({

    req(input$my_food)

    lapply(input$my_food, function(x) {

      df <- dat[dat$food == x,]

      contents <- div(h4(df$peanut_gallery),
                      h5(df$price),
                      p(sprintf("Isn't %s great? I love to eat it.", df$food)))

      box(title = df$food,
          width = 6,
          background = "red",
          collapsible = TRUE, collapsed = TRUE,
          uiOutput(contents) )

    })

  })

}

## RUN ##

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
htmltools::tagList(contents)
```

instead of

```
uiOutput(contents)
```

[image]